# How to get number of attributes in a dataclass?

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

I want to get the number of recipes I have in the `Recipes` class. How do I go about doing this?

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Recipe:
    ing1: str
    ing2: str
    ing3: str
   
class Recipes():
    pass
   
setattr(Recipes, 'Salad', Recipe('cabbage', 'lettuce', 'potato')
setattr(Recipes, 'Salad2', Recipe('tomato', 'lettuce', 'ranch')
print("There are %s number of recipes!" % # thing that gets number of attributes here #)
# prints 2
```

This is what I have so far. I want the thing at the end to print the number of recipes in the class (currently being 2).

Edit:
I can't use dict or lists because this is just a test for something I am working on.

Comment: May I ask why you don't just use a dictionary? This is really strange.

Comment: `newAttr` is particularly weird, as is the fact that you're setting attributes directly on the `Recipes` class instead of an instance of `Recipes`. This really sounds like a job for just a dict or list.

Comment: You have a `newAttr` function that assigns string values to the `__dict__`, which you never use. You're setting values directly on the `Recipes` *class* `__dict__` (not an instance, but the class itself) directly using `setattr`. There's a trailing `%` on the last non-comment line. Please make sure you understand the code you're writing as you write it. Programming is not a guess-and-check science, and if you don't understand what you've written then I promise you that two weeks down the road when you add more complexity, you'll deeply regret it.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo The trailing `%` was meant to be where the thing to get the number of attributes would go. I fixed the other thing.

Comment: You have titled this "How to get number of attributes in a dataclass?", but the question you are asking is about the `Recipes` class, which is **not** a dataclass.

Comment: You can examine the entries in the class's `__annotations__`.

Comment: @Karl: FWIW, I am the one who changed the title of the question based on my understanding of what was being asked.

Comment: The interesting thing is **the proposed solution still uses a dict**. Note that a class `__dict__` is still a mapping object, conceptually you can think of this as a dict which holds random attributes. So your requirement is actually not satisfied yet, if I'm understanding correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can traverse `Recipes.__dict__` to count all entries of type `Recipe`. This dict contains all set attributes and few other entries.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZDbasMwDIbv/RRab5ywUNb2rlDoM2y7D4pjN2bxAVktlLFnz@wel4sJbCT9/j/Ljmcegt9Mk6HgoEdGNWJKOoF1MRA/W0Lsn/llh3etbNRbATmsP6y2kJju1XpWbR7VzJuq@mqPhVrUpBmZqbrpDcgPHLGXzc1RSYVdhwedO3LUzEd1SWPIviDr@j/C@g@CgyuH5wRCr4YCEMoz7OBNmEDw1cApP@A@77Jte6u4bZeWtXuMbw3wOZNPNdj5v5QovNcdrISIZD1XZvE5aNKAeX1n8Qf80XWaIBig6z0vi3qafgE)

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Recipe:
    ing1: str
    ing2: str
    ing3: str
   
class Recipes():
    pass
   
setattr(Recipes, 'Salad', Recipe('cabbage', 'lettuce', 'potato'))
setattr(Recipes, 'Salad2', Recipe('tomato', 'lettuce', 'ranch'))

cnt = 0
for k, v in Recipes.__dict__.items():
    if type(v) is Recipe:
        cnt += 1

print(f"There are {cnt} number of recipes!")
```

Output:

```
There are 2 number of recipes!
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing I am confused about is you mentioned you don't want to work with `dict` objects, yet a class `__dict__` is a `mappingproxy` type object - which you can determine for ex. using `type(Recipe.__dict__)` - which I'd argue is technically a `dict` type.

The below alternate solution does not use a class level `__dict__` to store the Recipies at all, rather it uses a function `locals()` object to store it, just to draw a parallel between this and `__dict__`, which I feel are very similar in that regards.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class Recipe:
    ing1: str
    ing2: str
    ing3: str


def perform_recipe_related_hackery():
    locals()['Salad'] = Recipe('cabbage', 'lettuce', 'potato')
    locals()['Salad2'] = Recipe('tomato', 'lettuce', 'ranch')

    print(f'There are {len(locals())} number of recipes!')
    # prints 2


perform_recipe_related_hackery()
```

But if you wanted to be *really clever*, you could also get by with using `__dict__` and `setattr` as originally desired, *without* using a separate class at all! Here's an example of substituting a function instead of a class for this same purpose:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class Recipe:
    ing1: str
    ing2: str
    ing3: str


def perform_recipe_related_hackery():

    def my_func():
        ...

    setattr(my_func, 'Salad', Recipe('cabbage', 'lettuce', 'potato'))
    setattr(my_func, 'Salad2', Recipe('tomato', 'lettuce', 'ranch'))
    
    return my_func


x = perform_recipe_related_hackery()
print(f'There are {len(x.__dict__)} number of recipes!')
# prints 2
```

Out:

```
There are 2 number of recipes!
```